Why is the impedance of ferrite beads different if a current source is used?
From this article from Analog Devices:

I built this in ngspice with a current source.
This is my netlist:
* Ngspice-43 x64
I1 0 Vcomp  DC 0 SIN(0 1 1K 0 0 0) AC 1 ACPHASE 0
C1 0 _net0  1.678P 
L1 _net0 0  1.208U 
R1 0 _net0  1.082K tc1=0.0 tc2=0.0 
R2 _net0 Vcomp  300M tc1=0.0 tc2=0.0  

.control

ac dec 34 1meg 1000meg 
let Zr = real(ac.v(vcomp))
let Zi = imag(ac.v(vcomp))
let Z = ac.v(vcomp)
*write spice4qucs.ac1.plot v(Vcomp) Zr Zi Z

meas ac max_impedance max Z from=1e8 to=1e9


plot Zr Zi
plot Z
plot V(Vcomp)

.endc

.END


At 1GHz, the impedance is 8.789165 with a current source. With a voltage source, the impedance is 95.78128  at 1Ghz. You can see it's way off from the Analog Devices article.
I got the same result as the Analog Devices article when I replace the current source with a voltage source.

Hi. Where can I see it is way off?

@Tyassin At 1GHz, impedance is 8.789165 in current source. However, impedance is 95.78128 in voltage source at  1Ghz

Yes I see. Can you add your simulation setup?
How you checked if there is parasitics in your components?

I have now tried to simulate your circuit in LTSpice and I get the same curve as shown in the top of your post.

@Tyassin Can you post your curve and netlist?

Someone doesn't seem to be telling the truth.
Let's apply critical reading here.
Is the article correct?  Did they use the right source material?  Did they represent it correctly?  Let's examine that first.
Tyco is now TE; the part BMB2A1000LN2 returns a result here, 
https://www.te.com/en/product-2-1624117-0.html 
with the datasheet here: 
https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Data+Sheet%7F1773181%7FB%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_DS_1773181_B.pdf%7F2-1624117-0
From which we get our first truth:

Mind, this need not be representative of the part itself, but since we're not measuring real parts (and under what conditions e.g. DC bias, AC signal strength, proximity to materials, etc.), we can accept this as ground truth, and everything depending on it is thus only as true as this is.  We can freely doubt it, but separately, and for other reasons (like as above).
Superimposing this on the article's "confirmation" plot, we find a problem:

Where did that curve come from, then?  They claim,

Figure 1b shows the measured ZRX response of the BMB2A1000LN2 for a zero dc [sic] bias current using an impedance analyzer.

But no indication of what analyzer was used, what test setup, amplitude, how many were measured and what the variation was between them, etc.
Revised ground truth: the article likely ignores the datasheet, and uses their own reference -- data which we cannot check the veracity of, short of doing a bunch of measurements ourselves to try and figure it out.  Make a new assumption: use their plot as basis; the datasheet is now out of scope (aside from RDC, which they did read from the datasheet -- how inconsistent!).
We can check their plot in terms of their component values, then.  Entering them in an impedance tool of my own, and superimposing the plot here (thin red (Z), blue (R) curves):

The axes should be precise enough to match exactly, so something is still suspicious, but they are at least within engineering tolerances (you're never going to find a real ferrite bead matching within percent), and perhaps the exact component values, or errors or rounding in the computation or plotting, are relevant.
That leaves your plot; superimposing it (in negative, the green curve becomes purple) with my curves:

Possibly, however, you have the real component of V(Vcomp).
If you take the magnitude (mag()?) you should get the correct result.
You don't mention what version and environment of ngspice you're using, so I can't offer further insight as to what the plot is, or how it's produced.  It appears the expression should return a complex number, but a complex number per se cannot be cartesian plotted.  It is nonetheless returning some kind of result, so the plotting environment has made some kind of decision for you (a lossy operation: evidently the complex component is ignored).  Perhaps this is a plot setting, or a default, I don't know.
Whatever the case, we find a loss of information, or other discrepancy.  It seems your plotting tool is, in a sense, the one telling the lie.
Consult the documentation of your package/distribution to learn more.

To better explain the fitness (or lack thereof), consider a better effort to match the datasheet.  (Again, we don't know what values they measured and fitted to, but we can do a similar exercise with these data.)

Again, just a crude overlay, thin red/blue curves are my fit, fuzzy background is the datasheet curve stretched to fit.
This was attained with values of C1 = 1.31396p, R1 = 1.02075k, L1 = 2.15773u and R2 = 300m.  Better fitness (<10% say) requires representing the inductance as an RL equivalent (some Warburg element characteristic, but less than total).
Presumably, the fitness to their data, looked something like this, but we can't really know from here.

ngspice_43_64 on windows

mag really helps. Thanks a lot. I can't find What's the default one without mag in ngspice manual

Great answer. The deviation between this model and measurement is expected. The common bead model of parallel RLC gives a decent representation around the SRF, but real beads are more lossy at higher frequencies than predicted by such a model and the impedance before SRF also rises more gradually. Therefore, fitting a simple R-RLC model to measured data will fail your "plot-congruency" test every time

@tobalt Not quite what I meant, but perhaps I should add detail to explain that better. The RLC model in fact fits hi-Z multilayer FBs fairly well; I wouldn't complain about something that looks like this, as from the modest excursion with multiple crossings, an attempt has clearly been made.

There must be something with your simulation setup. I get the following result.

C1 0 N001 1.678p   
L1 N001 0 1.208µ   
R1 0 N001 1.082k   
R2 N001 Vin 300m  
I1 0 Vin AC 1   
.ac dec 1001 1MEG 1000MEG   
.backanno   
.end


Can you paste the netlist of your circuit here? Can you reformat it? It's very hard to read you can just copy netlist and use code format

@kile If you click on the image, you will get a full size version.

@Hearth Which image are you referring to ?

@kile The one showing Tyassin's circuit. It's easier to read if you click on it.

Using LTspice, the real part of the impedance at 1 GHz is 8.797 ohms, magnitude is 95.910 ohms when using a voltage or current source. Hence, I think your confusion is between real and magnitude impedance.
